# Query table values without session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a situation, where I save something to a postgres database with
 `with dbsession.begin() as session:` and as a next step, outside of the with-clause, I try to get the just updated value, with the following call:

`table.query.filter(table.name == full_name).all()`

the query works perfectly, except that it doesn't deliver the current (updated) values.

any idea, why this happens?
can someone explain, why the query without a session does not load the current data?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Postgres does not support READ UNCOMITTED and even if it did, that is not the typical default isolation level. You will need to `commit` in your session to see the changes outside it.  See Also : [PostgreSQL Transaction Isolation READ UNCOMMITTED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648607/218663)

Comment: But if I close the with clause, the commit and close of the session is completed. So this is not the problem. I even tested it manually and it did not change anything

Comment: commit will end a transaction not a session

Comment: You could try setting `engine.echo = True` before your `with` block to see if a COMMIT really does take place when it exits.